# Show that $\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n}$ converges a.s. for $X_n \sim U([0,1-2^{-n}])$ independent

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_{n})$ be a sequence of independent random variables and let $X_{n}$ have a uniform distribution on $[0, 1-2^{-n}]$. Prove that the sequence:

$$\frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+\dots+X_{n}}{n}$$

converges almost sure.  Find its limit.

I've proved that this sequence converges a.s. using Kolmogorov's theorm.
Because the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{Var} \, X_{n}}{n^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-2^{-n})^{2}}{12n^{2}}<\infty$ and $(X_{n})$ are independent so our sequence converges a.s (satisfies LLN).

How can I compute its limit? Should it be equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}EX_{n}$?

Comment: Hint or solution?

Comment: Give me a hint :D

Comment: Which "Kolmgorov theorem" do you use? (There are several ones with this name.) The one I'm thinking of actually requires that the series of the expectations converges and not only the series of the variances.

Comment: Woops. Made a calculation error, so i deleted my answer. sorry. Ill get back to you :)

Comment: @saz: I use this one: "If $(X_{n})$ is a sequence of independent random variables with $Var X_{n}<\infty$ for n=1,2,.... and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Var X_{n}}{n^{2}}$, then $(X_{n})$ satisfies LLN."

Comment: @Conformal: Thanks ;)

Comment: Complete solution: Start from $(U_n)$ i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$ and consider the event $$A=\{\forall n,U_n<1-2^{-n}\}.$$ Then $P(A)>0$ and $(U_n)$ conditional on $A$ is distributed like $(X_n)$. By the usual LLN, $P(B)=1$ where $$B=\left\{\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nU_k\to\frac12\right\},$$ hence $P(B\mid A)=1$ (this uses that $P(A)>0$) and, since $P(B\mid A)=P(C)$ where $$C=\left\{\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k\to\frac12\right\},$$ all this proves that $P(C)=1$, QED.

Comment: @Did If you call it a "complete solution", then why not write it as an answer....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kolmogorov's theorem implies that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies the strong law of large numbers, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mathbb{E}X_i) \to 0 \tag{1}$$

almost surely. Note that this does *not* necessarily imply that

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

converges.

---

**Hints:**

1. *If* the series $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}X_i$ converges, then, by $(1)$, $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges almost surely to exactly this limit.
2. Show the following statement: If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence such that $a_n \to a$, then $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \to a.$$
3. Use step 2 to conclude that $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}X_i \to \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Note that we can write $X_i=(1-2^{-i})U_i$
where $U_i$ are iid U[0,1] variables.
Now, apply SLLN on $\overline{U}_n$ and compute the limit of the difference $\overline{U_n}-\overline{X_n}$.

To make your calculations easier; Guess a limit of $\overline{X_n}$. (compare $\overline{X_n}$ and $ \overline{U_n}$ for large n)

(this makes Kolmogorov unnecessary)

I will post a solution if needed.